# TypeError: While Converting a List to String

Tags: typeerror

Converting a List to a String

```
def list_to_string(lis):
    string = ""

    for x in list:
        string += x
    return string

display = ""
_lis = ['b', '_', 'b', '_', '_', '_']

display = list_to_string(_lis)
print(display)
```

while I'am converting a list to string , I got an error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JITHU\PycharmProjects\100 Day\Test1.py", line 11, in <module>
    display = list_to_string(_lis)
  File "C:\Users\JITHU\PycharmProjects\100 Day\Test1.py", line 4, in list_to_string
    for x in list:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `for x in list:`,  your parameter is called `lis`

Comment: You spelled "list" wrong. Change your first line to `def list_to_string(list):`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. It is a good idea to try to find the problem yourself first; if you cannot, then you should make sure that you *ask a question* rather than simply describing the error.